# Deploying jekyll app on Cloudcannon fails

Tags: jekyll, cloudcannon

I am trying to deploy my jekyll app on the Cloudcannon CMS platform for Jekyll, but my build fails with this output:

```
Syncing raw files... done
Checking existing local bundle state... failed
Loading gem cache... 
Checking gem cache (bundle_cache/Jw8rkIm9v3Cmawv2raEpkN96fz3R5X1Q_XMn7xpGB1s.zip)... no cache

$ export JEKYLL_ENV="production"

$ ruby -v

ruby 2.3.8p459 (2018-10-18 revision 65136) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle version

Bundler version 2.0.1 (2019-01-04 commit d7ad2192f)

$ bundle config --global jobs 4

Configured concurrent installs!

$ bundle install

Using local cacheable path...
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
jekyll-feed-0.12.0 requires ruby version >= 2.4.0, which is incompatible with
the current version, ruby 2.3.8p459
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I update the ruby version correctly?

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 2.4.0"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?
```

I tried to change the jekyll-feed version and bundle it again but it gave me the same results and I don't want to remove that plugin because I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue could be from your `Gemfile.lock`.

**The latest version of `jekyll-feed` is `0.12.1`**
Correct your Gemfile to point to any version of `jekyll-feed` greater than or equal to `0.12.0`:

```
gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
```

The run `bundle update` so that the new version is installed and included in your `Gemfile.lock`

Then commit and push your updated Gemfile and the Gemfile.lock into your remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

Jordan from CloudCannon here.

ashmaroli is correct, you're referencing an invalid version number for jekyll-feed. Following ashmaroli's steps should resolve the problem.

As a side note, we'll be adding support for multiple Ruby versions within the next month or two. This will resolve any future incompatibilities with plugins that require a later version of Ruby.

If you have any more questions feel free to [contact us](https://cloudcannon.com/contact/), we're more than happy to help :)